# Is it possible to mix DRL with stream ConstraintProvider in Optaplanner for Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, optaplanner

I have extensive overtime rules implemented in DRL that I'd like to reuse in a rostering application developed with Optaplanner on Quarkus. The Quarkus guide shows an example using a streaming ConstraintProvider. I assume it is not a problem to instead use a SolverFactory with Quarkus. I doesn't seem possible that they can work together.

If they can't, is there some way to execute the DRL overtime rules from a constraint stream definition? I guess I could insert the employee and shifts into a drools session whenever there is a match in the stream but that doesn't seem like it would perform well.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that `scoreDRL` and `ConstraintProvider` can't be used together for a single solver - the architecture doesn't allow that, for various reasons.

We still support `scoreDRL` (it's not deprecated), but **`ConstraintProvider` is the future**, for ease-of-use, ease-of-testing and easy-of-learning reasons, especially now that 8.3.0.Final will bring it on par performance wise.

That being said, `scoreDRL` doesn't allow native compilation in Quarkus currently, an issue that's in our backlog. Also, to use `scoreDRL` with `optaplanner-quarkus`, replace the transitive dependency `drools-core-static` with `drools-core-dynamic`. Note that `ConstraintProvider` has none of these pitfalls: out-of-the-box, it supports Quarkus, native or non-native, and everything else.

Comment: If ContraintProvider is the future, then how does it support changing the rules after everything's been compiled?